# Check if element is off right edge of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I write an if condition that will run if an element is 60% of the window's width worth off the screen?

I've tried using `style.left > '40%'` but that doesn't seem to work. Or be right.

Comment: I believe you'll need to calculate a percentage from pixel values.

Comment: Can you use CSS media queries for this?  I don't think it will do exactly what you want - but it will let you tweak CSS based on resolution size / size of the browser window.

Comment: I'm lost in percentages. How wide is that element? You mean: "if 60% of the element's width is outside the right window edge"?? Can you please clarify? As it currently states it's hard to *get a picture* of what you want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use javascript and jQuery to do this pretty easily.
To find the right edge of your object (stored in memory as `f` here), use this code:

```
var rightEdge = f.width() + f.offset().left;
```

To find the screen width, you can use this code:

```
var screenWidth = $(window).width();
```

The amount of object that is "off screen" is calculated by subtracting `screenWidth` from `rightEdge`, therefore this boolean expression describes when the object is more than 60% off the screen:

```
rightEdge-screenWidth > f.width()*.6
```

Here's a working demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/YeyFj/

Comment: I love you. Thaaaaank youuuuu! Seriously. Your answer is so simple and so easy. I can totally use this to fix my navbar.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't directly answering your question, but I created this fiddle that might make it easier to play with the math that you need to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/5ucbX/

```
var w = $('#container').width();
var el = $('#el');
el.draggable({
    stop: function () {
        var ew = el.width();
        //this is your "formula"
        var l = el.offset().left + (ew * .6);
        if (l > w) {
            el.addClass('over')
        }
        else {
            el.removeClass('over')
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This adds the class once the drag is done. I need it to happen during the drag. That is the drag: option I believe.

Comment: The math is the same, as shown by the answer you selected.  Your question didn't say anything about draggable, so the event you want to use for draggable shouldn't matter.

Comment: Should have been a comment